# Backbone model parse method (collection / server)

Tags: parsing, backbone.js, collections

Please, help me :)

I have the backbone model:

```
var people = Backbone.Model.extend({
...
parse : function() {

  return response
}
})
```

And have the collection:

```
var group = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: people
...
})
```

Usually i get data by call collection **sync** method, but sometimes, i call model **fetch** method.

My backend return answer in format:

```
{code: 0, data: {'1': {name: 'alex'}, '2': {name: 'max'}}}
```

Problem: 
If i write model **parse** method for processing my backend answer - collection sync don't work (because server answer have another format), if i write **parse** method for collection - don't work backend processing.

How i can create universal processing?

I found way, see options in parse method and use else/if but i don't like it.

Comment: So the model URL sends back and accepts the usual JSON but the collection's URL sends back `{code: 0, data: {'1': {name: 'alex'}, '2': {name: 'max'}}}` and you need to convert the latter to an array of some sort?

Comment: Yes, i want work with model across collection, and model fetch method.

Comment: What's wrong with overriding [`Collection#parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) to rework the data?

Comment: I override collection#parse, that rule to parse incoming collection data, but i set in my collection property "Model: people" (Set collection model format), and when i fetch collection for every entry calling model#parse

Comment: So your model#parse is getting called or is not getting called? Do you want or need it to be called?

Answer (score -1):

**Option-1:**

Will using an additional _PeopleBase class help?

```
var _PeopleBase = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
})
var people = _PeopleBase.extend({
...
parse : function() {

  return response
}
})
```

The collection:

```
var group = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: _PeopleBase
...
parse : function() { //Collection parser


  return response
}

})
```

**Option-2:**
You can rely on the data returned to decide how to parse it if that is possible

```
parse : function(response, options) { 
  //Test the response with whichever way you can definitely differentiate them

  return response
}
```

***Option-3:***
Depending on who is the caller of the parse function:

```
parse : function(response, options) { 
    if (this instanceof People) {

    } else {

    }

  return response
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: It was variant too, but i don't like it :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I do it in mine (I have a lot of nested data and have to map existing objects to my views to ensure my view is updated without complete refresh):

//pass {parse: true} if Person has nested data that needs parsing as well

```
parse: function(response, xhr) {
                for(var key in this) {
                    if (key === 'person') {
                        var embeddedClass,
                            embeddedData = response[key], 
                            exsiting = this.get(key);

                       if (existing == null) {

                            embeddedClass = new Person(embeddedData, {parse: true}); 
                       } else {
                            existing.set(key, existing.parse(embeddedData));
                            embeddedClass = existing
                       } 
                       response[key] = embeddedClass;
                    }
                }
                return response;
            }
```

then when the new data comes and I need to parse it again manually, I call

```
this.set(this.parse(response));
```